# Do the following three expressions have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

My flight is scheduled for 7 p.m. from New York.

My flight is scheduled for New York at 7 p.m.

My flight is scheduled for New York, 7 p.m.

Comment: Only the first is unambiguous.

Comment: 2, 3. "scheduled **for** New York" --> will **depart** for NY, not **from** .

Comment: But word order makes all the difference. For instance, "My flight is scheduled for New York at 7 p.m." becomes unambiguous if you reorder it thus:  "My flight for New York is scheduled at/for 7 p.m."

Comment: @Kris My flight is scheduled from New York at 7 p.m. My flight is scheduled for 7 p.m. from New York. are same meaning? thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, the phrase *from New York* can move; *for* is preferable over *at* as a collocation for *scheduled.* By the way, what exactly is troubling you? Can you add more details as to why you are asking so can help better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They could have the same meaning, depending upon context. Generally, though, the latter two (..."for New York") are slightly more ambiguous, as it's not clear whether the flight is originating in New York, or whether it is terminating there. There is less ambiguity in the first choice.

Answer (score -2):

One cannot tell whether they have the same meaning, because none of them are clear enough; mainly because none specifies whether the time mentioned is a departure or arrival time. To make it clear, include "scheduled to depart" or "scheduled to arrive".  (That is, if you actually want to be met at your destination city, when you arrive, rather than at your departure city, when you depart.) If your flight is bound "for" New York, it would be clear to say "my flight TO New York".  (These are not the kind of instructions you would give to someone you wanted to drop you off at the airport; they know which city you are departing from.)

Comment: I've never hear anyone say "My flight is scheduled for [time] from [place]" when they actually meant "The arrival of my flight from [place] is scheduled to occur at [time]". (I'd wager that you haven't either.) Whenever someone says "My flight is scheduled for [time] ... ", they always mean "My flight is scheduled **to depart at** [time].

Comment: Well, since the three sentences mix "from New York" and "for New York", some refer implicitly to departing from New York, and some to arriving there. They are not different ways of saying the same thing; they are vague, ambiguous ways of saying two different things.  One says a flight departs "from", one does not say it departs "for" (not without specifying a destination.)

Comment: On that point I agree (see my comments under the OP's question).